# Как считывать в double числа с запятой вместо точки?

Tags: c++

Входные данные с запятой, но программа работает неправильно, если стоит запятая. Есть ли способ не используя библиотек (кроме стандартных) считать числа с запятой в переменную double?

Comment: А через что вы парсите double сейчас?

Comment: Заменить запятые на точки и дальше как обычно - не?

Comment: Дело в том что входные данные задаёт программа (не моя) и там на вход даются числа с запятой

Comment: Данные принимаются через стандартный поток ввода, либо с документа. Но я пользуюсь 1 вариантом.

Comment: С точкой программа работает правильно, а вот с запятой проблемы.

Comment: @Alone_Fox у вас очень занимательный ответ, и я вам охотно верю. Но все же прошу ответить на мой вопрос: каким образом вы (или не вы) парсите строку в вещественное число сейчас?

Comment: Фрагмет кода, где парсится строка в тип double в студию! :)

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220861/how-can-i-set-the-comma-to-be-a-decimal-point, вероятно, это то, что вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @AGS17 через стандартный поток ввода. То есть `double n;  cin>>n;`

Comment: @Alone_Fox Запятую/точку определяет локаль. Значит либо менять локаль, либо читать в строку, подменять запятые на точки, парсить в число, как описывалось выше

Comment: @b2soft как поменять локаль? Можете помочь?

Comment: @Alone_Fox пробуйте `std::setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char * dot = "3.1415926", * comma = "3,1415926";
    {
        double pd, pc;
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout.imbue(locale("Russian"));

        sscanf(dot,"%lf",&pd);           // С точкой не читает
        cout << pd << endl;              // Вывод в русской локали

        sscanf(comma,"%lf",&pc);         // Чтение с запятой
        cout << pc << endl;              // Вывод в русской локали

        istringstream sc(comma);
        sc.imbue(locale("Russian"));
        sc >> pc;                        // Чтение с запятой
        cout.imbue(locale("C"));         // Вывод в стандартной локали
        cout << pc << endl;              // с точкой
    }
}
```

Ну, что-то типа этого... Компилировалось VC++2015.

А вообще эти локали где работают, где нет... так что просто заменять запятую на точку и работать - тоже может быть неплохим решением...